# Kendo Validation messages too long for background

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, grid

If I run the JS Fiddle proposed as a solution to [Kendo Grid Custom Validation Rules Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390660/kendo-grid-custom-validation-rules-not-working), change the validation message from "Error" to something like "The product name must not be blank. Please enter a valid product name.", and if the first product name is an empty string and I leave the field, the message is to long for the yellow background. So my question is simple, perhaps the answer not so much...

How can I ensure that the message background covers the entire error message, either by changing its width or height (with word wrap, as neccesary, if the width can't be changed) to accommodate the entire error message no matter how long it is?

Comment: It appears the example at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation does do word wrapping on long error messages, but I'm just not seeing the code that's doing that. :(

Comment: The CSS appears to have changed in the 2014.2 release of Kendo UI. The behavior you see in the demo is now the default. See this updated version of the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DidierLoiseau/0fzr1xuk/